# gRPC java does LongArrayList resize when deserializing?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I'm using grpc 1.37.0 and Java. As far as I can see from the generated code, when doing deserialization on an `int64` list as below, the code essentially creates an empty `LongArrayList` and adds to it.

My question is, **does that have the resizing problem when deserializing the elements from the message?** Just like now Java ArrayList needs to resize to twice as big and do a full copy, is that the same for gRPC `LongArrayList`?

For example my proto looks like below, when I'm sending a list of blockIDs from the server to client:

```
message BlockIdList {
  repeated int64 blockId = 1;
}
```

From the generated java code I can see below. I'm trying to read the code and trace down where the elements are added to `blockId_` and see if resizing happened, but I was not able to find out. Could someone help point me to the correct direction?

```
class BlockIdList {
    private com.google.protobuf.Internal.LongList blockId_ = emptyLongList();

    // By the time I call getBlockIdList(), the list is already there
    // When were the elements added to the list?
    public java.util.List<java.lang.Long>
        getBlockIdList() {
      return ((bitField0_ & 0x00000001) != 0) ?
               java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(blockId_) : blockId_;
    }

    // This size is known only after the list is completed?
    public int getBlockIdCount() {
      return blockId_.size();
    }
}
```